# Why the memory allocation like this when the const reference release to a different type in g++4.7.3

Tags: c++, memory, g++

My compiler is g++ 4.7.3

```
long i = 2222;
const long& lref = i;
const int& iref = i;
printf("i=%p lref=%p iref=%p \n", &i , &lref, &iref);
```

The result is

```
i=0xbfd78760 lref=0xbfd78760 iref=0xbfd78764
```

Why the address of `iref` is higher than `i`

I think it may just like this:
when `const int&` reference to `long`, it like

```
int temp = i
const int& iref = temp;
```

==========================================================

CODE2

However when the code like

```
long i = 2222;
const long& lref = i;
const int& iref = i;
int a = 10;
int b = 10;

printf("i=%p lref=%p iref=%p a=%p b=%p\n", &i , &lref, &iref, &a, &b);
```

The result is

```
i=0xbfade768 lref=0xbfade768 iref=0xbfade774 a=0xbfade76c b=0xbfade770
```

Why the address of `a` and `b` is lower than `iref` in the stack?

==========================================================

CODE3

When the code like

```
long i = 2222;
const long& lref = i;
const int& iref = i;
printf("i=%p lref=%p iref=%p \n", &i , &lref, &iref);
```

The result is

```
i=0xbfbe3f84 lref=0xbfbe3f84 iref=0xbfbe3f83
```

When the type of `iref` is `char`,why the address of `iref` is lower than `i`?

Can somebody tell my why,  thanks you!

Comment: what does it matter at which addresses these variables are?

Comment: It may matter if OP is writing low-level and/or embedded code. However, this is definitely not the way to do that.

Comment: understand the memory allocating

Comment: @CLS There's not much important to understand about that here. There are other things you need to understand here and those are about the language semantics.

Comment: AFAIK the compiler is not required to "allocate" local variables in the stack in the same order as they are defined. It is not even required to allocate them at all: they may be put directly in registers, optimized out entirely, etc. So to me relying on a particular stack memory layout seems unsafe and a waste of time. (Note: in your last snippet I guess that `const int& iref = i;` was rather `const char& iref = i;`.)

Comment: @gx_   the code just for test,i just could not understand why for different the memory allocate is different???

Comment: @CLS As I said you may get different results with different compilers (or different versions of the same compiler, or different options for the same version of the same compiler...). Here's the same example with another GCC, and different results (notably for the first snippet): http://ideone.com/EBvfpm (Also, no need for triple question marks.) There's no understanding "why", the compiler can do whatever it wants (usually the reason is optimal efficiency).

Comment: @CLS I'd like to bring to your attention that you have a much higher chance of being taken seriously if you write calmly. That is, proper capitalization of sentences, capitalization of I and only one question mark instead of 2 to 3. Right now you're giving the impression you're incredibly confused.

Comment: @nightcracker I am so sorry for my poor English.What about the style now?

Comment: @gx_  Yes, it may release to the compiler.Thank you.

Comment: @CLS Better. Make sure to keep a space between sentences, but keep up the good effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right, `iref` is indeed a seperate memory location assigned a temporary.

The order of the memory addresses is up to the compiler, and apparently the code generation ordered the stack like this. Why exactly g++ orders it like this I do not know - you'll probably have to dig deep into either g++ internal documentation or even source code.

Keep in mind however, on most systems if the address on the stack is lower it means the value is **higher** up the stack, because stacks usually grow downwards.

Comment: if my intuition is right?? the next two code is not so Conform to the my intuition?? that is what i want to konw

Comment: One possible clue is padding: it may be that g++ maximize the use of the stack by reordering elements so as to minimize padding.

Comment: Yes, it may release to the compiler.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
long i = 2222;
const long& lref = i;
```

Here, the reference type matches the object type, so `lref` can be a reference to `i`. Hence, you see the same address for both.

```
const int& iref = i;
```

Here, the type doesn't match, so `iref` can't refer directly to `i`. One might expect this to give an error; however, there are two loopholes in the language:

- `i` can be converted to a temporary of type `int`; and
- a constant reference can refer to a temporary (extending the lifetime of the temporary to match that of the reference).

The (perhaps surprising) result is that `iref` refers to a separate value, with a different address to `i`.